# $U,W$ are sub spaces in $R^n$ that $R^n = U + W$

Tags: linear-algebra

$U,W$ are sub spaces in $R^n$ that $R^n = U + W$ Then

> $(a)$ If $U \oplus W = R^n$, then $U \cap W = \{0\}$
>
> $(b)$ For every $ x \in R^n $ there are vectors (only $2$) $u \in U$, $w \in W$ that $x = u + w$

I want to understand how they proved (a) from (b).

It is written like that: (Proof)

let's take a vector $x \in U \cap W$. We can write $x$ as $x = x + 0 = 0 + x$. and because of (b), we can say that there is only one possible way to make that sum above. Thus $x = 0$. Meaning, there's only one vector in $U \cap W$ which is the $\{0\}$ vector.

Question: How did they conclude from  $x = x + 0 = 0 + x$ and from $(b)$ that $x$ must be zero?

Comment: So what they prove is that (a) and (b) are equivalent? If so, then the idea is that $x\in U$, $0\in W$ and $0\in U$, $x\in W$ are two possible choice of vectors such that $u+v=x$. Because there is supposed to be only one such choice, the two must coincide, which means $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Because (b) requires that the representation must be **unique**: if 
$$x + 0 = 0 + x,$$
check the first position of the left hand side and right hand side of the equation, the uniqueness implies that $x = 0$.

Comment: because the representation must be unique, the left vector in the left equation must equal to the left vector (zero) in the right equation, and same with the right vectors, thus $x = 0$?

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $x \in U \cap W$ is not $0$. Then we have $x=x+0=0+x$ viewed in $U \oplus W$. But then we found two different decompositions of $x$ contradicting (b).